# What is the difference between STL:type_traits and BOOST:type_traits?

Tags: boost, stl, type-traits

I saw that STL needs a special directive when compiling type_traits. Does this mean that STL::type_traits has compile-time reflection?

Is this the only difference or are there others?

Comment: What compiler? What directive?

Comment: compiler = gcc , directive = -std=c++0x

Answer (score 2):

Standard library `type_traits` are available only in C++11, so you have to enable c++11 support in your compiler, and this is what `-std=c++0x` oiption does in your case.

`Boost.TypeTraits` library is much more portable and it would work in C++03 mode as well, with [some limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/intrinsics.html). Of course, it uses c++11 support where available.